PowerShell cmdlet Get-Team -NumberOfThreads
My question concerns the management of teams in MS Teams:
I want to use Get-Team in PowerShell to retrieve all teams in my environment.
Can someone explain to me what the -NumberOfThreads attribute does? What is the difference between Get-Team, Get-Team -NumberOfThreads 1 and Get-Team -NumberOfThreads 20? Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't really help me.
Can I use this to solve my problem that Get-Team only retrieves just over half of the teams, after which the error "too many request" always appears?
I estimate that this is due to a limitation in the API, as there are almost 2000 teams in total.
Tried to read the docmentation und search the Web

This sounds like it would be really easy to test - run Get-Team with different argument values and observe if the behavior changes

Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestions or still looking for any help?

I was actually able to solve my problem by trial and error.
I was hoping that someone could tell me exactly what the parameter does. I couldn't figure it out for myself.
